# If $X=Y+Z$ with known pdf of $X$, are $Y$ and $Z$ unique?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, density-function, independence, decomposition

Say there are random variables such that $X=Y+Z$ with $Y$, $Z$ independent; knowing the pdfs of $Y$ and $Z$, one can (technically) find the pdf of $X$. Taking it from the other side: if one knows the pdf of $X$, is the decomposition $X=Y+Z$ unique? Or can there be other choices for $Y$ and $Z$ that give the same pdf of $X$?

Comment: Please contemplate the circumstance $X=Y_0+W+Z_0$ with $Y_0,W,Z_0$ independent.  By setting $(Y,Z)=(Y_0+W, Z_0)$ and $(Y,Z)=(Y_0,W+Z_0)$ you obtain two different decompositions of the form $X=Y+Z$ with $Y$ and $Z$ independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because if $a,b$ are such that $a+b = x$ then $a' + b' =x$ too where $a' = a-c$ and $b' = b+c$ for any $c$.

The decomposition is not even unique up to additive constants.  For example suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$.  Then (independent) $Y\sim N(0,\sigma_Y^2)$ and $Z \sim N(0,\sigma_Z^2)$ have $Y + Z \sim N(0, \sigma_Y^2 + \sigma_Z^2)$ and there are many positive solutions to $\sigma_Y^2 + \sigma_Z^2 = 1$ (top right quarter of unit circle!).

Comment: The example with normals is convincing. But about the first paragraph: doesn't it have the same issue? I.e., I'm asking about the decomposition of $x$ as $a+b$; you write $a'=a-c$, $b'=b+c$ - this leads to a question whether these decompositions are unique. By your argument, this would lead to an infinite series of such decompositions, i.e. the question about uniqueness being asked repeatedly ad infinitum with no conclusion altogether.

Comment: I don't see an issue :)  Perhaps it's easier to understand as a proof by contradiction: let us suppose the decomposition is unique, i.e. for a given $X$ there is a unique decomposition into sum of independent $Y$ and $Z$.  But then we simply observe that $Y' = Y+1$ and $Z' = Z-1$ are still independent and have sum $X$.  So the decomposition is not unique.